# Laravel/Aws - Doesnot delete file after upload s3 bucket with MultipartUploader

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, multipart

I'm tring upload large video file to my Amazon S3 bucket with aws api.

```
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient(), $localFullFilePath, [
  'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
  'key'    => $s3fullFullFilePath,
]);

try {
  $result = $uploader->upload();
  Log::info("Upload complete");
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
  Log::info($e->getMessage());
}
```

Then I am deleting my uploaded videos with below code.

```
foreach ($oldVideos as $oneVideo) {
  // $localFullFilePath = $localFilePath . $oneVideo;     
  unlink($localFullFilePath);
}
```

My videos uploading successfully but when i try to delete my local file, it gives 'permission denied' error.

I am sure it is not file permission error because it occurs only when I uploading file to S3. 
I think api does not `fclose` file after reading.

Do you suggest any tips or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

did you gave yourself permission in the map structure? That's also what happend to me last time :P

You must give yourself the permission to Upload & Delete

Comment: When I comment upload method in below code, file be deleted succesfully. That's why i m sure, it is not permission error related to OS

Answer (score 0):

You're right, api does not close file. You can do it manually:

```
// open a file
$source = fopen($localFullFilePath, 'rb');

// pass a resource, not a path
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient(), $source, [
  'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
  'key'    => $s3fullFullFilePath,
]);

// upload
try {
  $result = $uploader->upload();
  Log::info("Upload complete");
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
  Log::info($e->getMessage());
}

// close
fclose($source);

// now we can remove it
```